# Strange results with Boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I was playing around with Boost::regex and this is the first time I'm working with regex as well as Boost, so forgive me if the question is really stupid.
I am getting a NO_MATCH with the following values:

```
actual_name = "q\[0\]123"
user_name   = "q[0]123"
```

P.S. In the debugger, when I printed `actual_name` it showed - `q\\[0\\]123`. But, when I did actual_name.size(), it came out to be 9.

Here is my code:

```
boost::regex regexpr( actual_name );
boost::match_results<pstring::const_iterator> what;
boost::regex_match(user_name, what, regexpr);

if(what[0].matched)
{
     // Match found
}
else
{
    // NO_match found
}
```

I tried the same combination of `regular_expression = "q\[0\]123"` and `test-string = "q[0]123"` on [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) and it returns a Complete_Match there.

What am I missing?

Comment: More backslashes. You need to escape the backslash, so that it makes it through being interpreted by the c++ compiler, to be seen by the regex processor, so you end up with an actual square bracket, rather than a character range containing just `'0'`. i.e. `"Q\\[0\\]123"`.

Comment: @BoBTFish: In the debugger, when I printed actual_name it showed - `q\\[0\\]123`. But, when I did `actual_name.size()`, it came out to be 9. What does that mean?

Comment: Your debugger doesn't show regex strings, it shows C strings. In C, the single character '\' is *displayed* as '\\'. This is so your debugger can also show other 'escaped' characters such as '\t' and '\n'. It seems you get confused by C notation (double backslash) versus regexp notation. For a regexp that needs a single backslash, you need to insert *two* in your C code. And that's what the debugger shows as well. If you output your result with a standard printf or cout, you will see a single backslash where expected, because these routines do *not* escape special characters.

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, I had got confused by the C notation and the regex notation. Figured it out later. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"q\[0\]123"` compiles?

`\[` is not a backslash character followed by an opening square bracket character. It's an escape sequence. I don't remember it being a valid escape sequence, but it might be an extension in your compiler.

You need to escape the backslashes like `"q\\[0\\]123"`, or use a C++11 raw string literal like `R"(q\[0\]123)"`.

Comment: In the debugger, when I printed actual_name it showed - `q\\[0\\]123`. But, when I did `actual_name.size()`, it came out to be 9. What does that mean?

Comment: I understand that if I were to initialise actual_name with `"q\[0\]123"` it won't. The values are computed from different code and passed on for regex-matching. Please refer my previous comment and let me know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your actual assignment code to `actual_name`, it seems you're not doubling up your `\\` to protect them from the C++ compiler: `"q\\[0\\]123"` …

Comment: I understand that. Please refer to my comment. May be it'll help you in helping me ;) :)